# Redirect if password is expired in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle12c

I am using Database Account authentication in an app. I want to automatically redirect user to Reset Password Application (it is separate app) if password is expired.

I have created `Before Header` process which is following

```
begin
    if instr(owa_util.get_cgi_env('QUERY_STRING'),'&notification_msg=Password%20Expired/') > 0 then
        apex_application.g_unrecoverable_error := true;
        owa_util.redirect_url('http://www.oracle.com');
    end if;
end;
```

The issue is that `notification_msg` is not in plain text. It is like below

`&notification_msg=UGFzc3dvcmQgRXhwaXJlZDxkaXYga..#moregibberish`

Due to this QUERY_STRING is not matched, hence can't redirect. Any suggestion on how could I identify if Password is expired of if I could encode 'Password Expired' (plain notification text) into same as `&notification_msg` value through code?

Using Apex 21.2 and Database 12c

Comment: You may consider using a regular expression to decide if it is expired or not instead of instr. Maybe you can check https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/B14251_01/adfns_regexp.htm#CHDIBCGD for more examples.

Comment: @cengizsevimli even with regex it won't work as the hash or encode value for notification_msg is changing every time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved through different approach

1. Created After Header Process in Pre rendering with following code

```
declare
    v_count number;
begin

    select count(1)
    into v_count
    from apex_workspace_activity_log
    where application_id = :APP_ID
    and error_on_component_type = 'AUTHENTICATION'
    and error_on_component_name = 'DATABASE ACCOUNT'
    and apex_session_id = :APP_SESSION
    and view_timestamp between systimestamp - interval '2' second and systimestamp  + interval '2' second
    and upper(error_message) like upper('Password Expired (user=' || :P101_USERNAME || ')');

    if v_count > 0 then
        apex_application.g_unrecoverable_error := true;
        apex_util.redirect_url(p_url => 'f?p=9999999:1:'||:APP_SESSION);
    end if;  
end;
```